# Ember inject function

Tags: ember.js

I have some function which i use in couple controllers

```
 App.AController=Ember.Controller.Extend({
    area:function(){}
});
App.BController=Ember.Controller.Extend({
    area:function(){}
});
```

cause i new in Ember i want something to write function in one place and then inject function in Controllers. I try something with services but doesn't work i got error that `Ember.Service` is not defined, so if someone can write example! 
I use ember 1.10.

Comment: You can create util and import it to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ember-cli` just create a file `app/utils/area.js`:

```
export default function () {...};
```

and then you can import it and use it:

```
import area from 'myapp/utils/area`;
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  area,
});
```

---

However if you'r not using `ember-cli`, this question is not ember specific. Then it depends how you organize your code. But you *really* should check out `ember-cli`!

But always remember, this is just javascript. This is valid code:

```
function area() {
    ...
}

App.AController=Ember.Controller.Extend({
    area
});
App.BController=Ember.Controller.Extend({
    area
});
```